# How to set limit per user month wise in shopping cart application?

Tags: php, android

I am developing client server based ecommerce application. I am using android and php.

My requirement is that every user having limit 1500 per month to purchase item. Means every month he can purchase upto 1500 only.

I am really stuck in developing logic how to restrict user for month wise.Can any one help me it would be more appreciate.

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve it? We can check your logic and correct it if required. Try posting block of codes, it is always helpful in understanding the problem.

Comment: have a purchase count filed in your server db , once a purchase is done add that count in that field . On every order check that count.Simple

Comment: it is good if you develop that logic on server side... from date 1 keep calculating the purchase and when amount reaches to limit descard request from that perticular user app

Comment: thanks so much guys for your reply..so far i achieve to set the limit 1500 per user on purchase count feild in db but how to handle user month wise dat bit finding difficult,